# SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found on Weblogic 10gR3

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, jax-ws, weblogic-10.x

I'm in the process of migrating a webservice application that worked perfectly on Weblogic 9 into Weblogic 10gR3.
The small difficulty is that my application uses JAX-WS and on Weblogic 9 I had to include JAX-WS libraries in my WAR. But on WLS 10, those libraries are already integrated.
To avoid conflicts, I put my WAR inside an EAR with the following weblogic-application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application>
  <application-param>
    <param-name>webapp.encoding.default</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </application-param>
  <prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>com.sun.xml.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.bind.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.jws.*</package-name>
  </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

Thanks to that, I don't have ClassCastExceptions anymore, but I have another exception:

```
javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factoryProvider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found
at javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory.getInstance(SAAJMetaFactory.java:85)
at javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:148)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<init>(SOAPVersion.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<clinit>(SOAPVersion.java:83)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.BindingID.<clinit>(BindingID.java:318)
at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:294)
at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:45)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1236)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:262)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:109)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:861)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:156)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:287)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:244)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:187)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:465)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:175)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1784)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2999)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1371)
```

What's weird is that this SAAJMetaFactoryImpl class it says it cannot find is part of JDK 1.6.0_17 that is used by WLS10 on MACOSX 10.6 where it is installed.

Any idea what might cause this conflict?

Comment: If you want them loaded from the war, shouldnt it be prefer-web-inf-classes set to true?

Comment: I think this part works already. Plus, isn't prefer-web-inf-classes used to override weblogic classes with classes from WEB-INF/classes?
Because here what I want to do is override classes from Weblogic with classes from WEB-INF/lib/*.jar

Comment: It works for both - your lib/*.jar will get loaded in preference to Weblogic's own version.

Comment: Anyway. Once again, it seems that this part works. The question is why is it not able to find a class that belongs to the JDK it's running on?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how this will benefit but it worked for my use case which required a boot delegation settings.

Each application server would have a configuration settings file (usually <application server name>.properties e.g., weblogic.properties, sling.properties....). You may have to add the following line

"**<application server name>.bootdelegation.com.sun=com.sun.***"

For example

> For weblogic Server    : "weblogic.bootdelegation.com.sun=com.sun.* "
>   For Adobe CQ Server : "sling.bootdelegation.com.sun=com.sun.*"

And this will work for most of the problem associated with this thread issue.

Now coming to the explanation, com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl is already packaged with **rt.jar** which is a part of every run time library of JDK/JRE. However this package is totally ignored while booting the application. When specifically instructed to load through application configuration, the correct implementation class is loaded (which is what **.bootdelegation.** does).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/programming/classloading.html#wp1098468), when you specify `prefer-application-packages` for `com.sun.xml.*` , those package are loaded from the application, not the system classloader.